# How to communicate with my former co-advisor and professors I want to decline a PhD offer to re-apply next year?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, application

Recently, I got accepted into a very top PhD program in humanities will full-funding in the UK (Cambridge). On paper, my situation seems ideal. However, I strongly doubt whether or not I should accept the offer.  My main concern is that I'm not that interested in the research topic. I do not see myself working on this topic for years and leaving my home country for it. I only applied to one PhD program this year due to personal issues (health) - and luckily got accepted into this program - but I don’t think this is the best fit for me. However, I am concerned for several reasons. First, I don’t know how to communicate that to the professors who wrote my recommendation letters. I am afraid they would take it badly (especially my former MA co-advisor with who I may like to stay working with if I am not going to this university) and will not be willing to write recommendation letters for me again if I want to apply to other PhD programs next year. I know it is better to refuse an offer than dropping out of the program if I don't like it but still, I am not sure how it could be perceived. I acknowledge that my research interests shifted a bit but I have no idea how to communicate that without making mistakes. The second reason is that I am afraid the university and supervisor will take it badly and that they will « blacklist » me if I want to apply again next year with another supervisor suiting my research interests better at the same university.

1. Would professors refuse to write recommendation letters for PhD applications a second time?
2. Would my former MA co-advisor - who is very cautious about her reputation - refuse to write a letter a second time for me or work with me? Should I tell her the truth about my situation or something else (such as my personal issue)? I've also asked her if I can talk to her about my future after receiving the offer, but she won't see me in person to discuss (« lack of time » she told me) and only wants to communicate via email. I don't know what I can tell her... I also explained my difficult situation with one of my ex-advisor in this post: [How to deal with my former MA advisor behavior](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/192404/how-to-deal-with-my-former-ma-advisor-behavior))

Thank you.

Comment: Too many questions here, but more importantly, too personal for a good answer. It depends on your own goals and values which are probably quite unique. But I doubt that blacklisting is something to worry about.

Comment: I agree with Buffy. Maybe if this had just one question in it we could sift it down to something that's not so personal we can't answer it. Though also, it's a bit hard not to toss in a traditional saying: A bird in the hand is worth 2 in the bush.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers. I edited my post to suppress a few questions and make it a bit "less" personal. It is just that my situation is a bit difficult and I try to make no "diplomatic mistakes" with my professors if I don't want to go there, even though I know I may not joined another program next year if I decline it.

Comment: They might not "blacklist" you but just because you got accepted one year does not at all mean that you can count on being accepted the following year. It feels like you are fixating too much on what you call "diplomatic mistakes" and not enough on the significant element of pure luck involved in such decisions. Don't forget that you are comparing a very hypothetical situation - IF you get accepted next year AND you don't again at the last minute decide that you don't really want to work on that topic after all - with the actual fact that you DID get accepted into a top Ph.D. program.

Comment: I know that being accepted one year doesn't mean I will be accepted another one. Since the beginning, I know I would prefer staying in my home country and working in the same field of my MA. But due to the difficult relationship I had with my main advisor, this option is compromised and I was obliged to look for other options. This one stood out, but I knew from the start that this research topic was not exactly in line with my main research interests. I just don’t know how to communicate this issue with my ex-advisor who changed behavior with me and professors. Any advice on this aspect?